# Ошибка при запуске приложения собраного qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, cmake, qml

Помогите исправить ошибку при запуские exe файла. Вот cmake

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.0 )

set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

# Widgets finds its own dependencies.
find_package ( Qt5 COMPONENTS  Widgets Core Gui Qml QuickWidgets Network 
SerialBus REQUIRED )

set ( CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON )
set ( CMAKE_AUTORCC ON )
set ( CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON )

file ( GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp )
file ( GLOB_RECURSE MOC_HEADERS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*.hpp )

include_directories( $ENV{MODBUS64_ROOT}/include )
link_directories( $ENV{MODBUS64_ROOT}/lib )
message( $ENV{MODBUS64_ROOT} )
set( alianc_libs modbus )

set ( RESOURCES resources/qml.qrc )

include_directories ( ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include )

add_executable ( alliance ${SOURCES} ${MOC_SRCS} ${MOC_HEADERS} ${RESOURCES} 
)

qt5_use_modules ( alliance Widgets Qml Quick Gui Core)
target_link_libraries( alliance ${alianc_libs} Qt5::Widgets Qt5::QuickWidgets 
Qt5::Quick Qt5::Qml Qt5::Gui Qt5::Core )
```

Ошибка 0xc00007b, либы подкачены через windeployq, так же сторонии либы добавлины к exe руками. Машина на которой хочу запустить не имеет qt, операционная система win10.

Comment: 0xc00007b - это у вас в коде судя по всему, если бы не хватало длл, то ругнулось бы на них

Comment: @goldstar_labs нет приложение запускается на 3 тачках. С qtCreatora.

Comment: @goldstar_labs не запускается только когда готовый exe запускаешь.

Comment: Найс кто то минус поставил, обожаю комьюнити.

Comment: поставьте в реестре, чтобы dump писался при падении программы и смотрите его отладчиком, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/collecting-user-mode-dumps

Comment: Может быть куча вариантов, почему происходит ошибка. Для начала, убедитесь, что у вас есть все dll и они нужной разрядности. [Fix: Error 0xc00007b “Application was unable to start correctly”](https://appuals.com/fix-error-0xc00007b-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly/)

Comment: "нет приложение запускается на 3 тачках. С qtCreatora" не понял, на трех тачках запускается, на одной нет, или на трех запускается с креатора, но не запускается екзешником?

Comment: @BeardedBeaver все верно

Comment: что верно? у меня вопрос содержит два взаимоисключающих варианта, разделенных словом "или". какой из них верный?

Comment: @BeardedBeaver не запускается если открывать exe файл. На тех что есть креатор запускается. Вопрос я уже решил)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

мэйк тут ничем не спасёт.
дело точно в либах.
windoeployqt собирает только "запчасти" от самой qt. сторонние библиотеки она не собирает. надо выискивать чего не хватает. иногда бывает что зависимость даже не первого порядка (например тот с тем же libxml надо тащить libiconv и zlib)
можно посмотреть какие библиотеки подгружаются с помощью этого
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer

ну и потом докинуть чего не хватает

Comment: Вы почти правы , только есть специальная утилита называется она pe viewer и конечно же смотрю через нее что есть ли у меня все либы или чего то не хватает. Но все либы на месте

Comment: Отмечу этот ответ как верный но опишу то что произошло. Проверив библиотеки тулой увидел что они все на месте , начал запускать но не помогло. Ошибки при нехватки библиотек показывает сразу (выдает ошибку). Оказалось все проще , почему то windeploy взял либы не из той версии компилятора. Не совпадают только время на первый взгляд так что было не очевидно что и по чему. Всем спасибо